# Python: Find subsets across many-to-many mapping

Tags: python, set, many-to-many

I am trying to work with a many-to-many mapping, finding subsets of one set that map to specific subsets of the other set.

I have many genes.  Each gene is a member of one or more COGs (and vice versa), eg.

- gene1 is member of COG1
- gene1 is member of COG1003
- gene2 is member of COG2
- gene3 is member of COG273
- gene4 is member of COG1
- gene5 is member of COG273
- gene5 is member of COG71
- gene6 is member of COG1
- gene6 is member of COG273

I have a short set of COGs that represents an enzyme, eg. COG1,COG273.

I want to find all sets of genes that between them have membership of every COG in the enzyme, but without unnecessary overlaps (in this case, for instance, 'gene1 and gene6' would be spurious as gene6 is already a member of both COGs).

In this example, the answers would be:

- gene1 and gene3
- gene1 and gene5
- gene3 and gene4
- gene4 and gene5
- gene6

Although I could get all members of each COG and create a 'product', this would contain spurious results (as mentioned above) where more genes than necessary are in the set.

My mappings are currently contained in a dictionary where the key is the gene ID and the value is a list of the COG IDs of which that gene is a member.  However I accept that this might not be the best way to have the mapping stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, they have inspired me to hack something together using recursion.  I want to deal with arbitrary gene-cog relationships, so it needs to be a general solution.  This should yield all sets of genes (enzymes) that between them are members of all required COGs, without duplicate enzymes and without redundant genes:

```
def get_enzyme_cogs(enzyme, gene_cog_dict):
    """Get all COGs of which there is at least one member gene in the enzyme."""
    cog_list = []
    for gene in enzyme:
        cog_list.extend(gene_cog_dict[gene])
    return set(cog_list)

def get_gene_by_gene_cogs(enzyme, gene_cog_dict):
    """Get COG memberships for each gene in enzyme."""
    cogs_list = []
    for gene in enzyme:
        cogs_list.append(set(gene_cog_dict[gene]))
    return cogs_list

def add_gene(target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict, cog_gene_dict, proposed_enzyme = None, fulfilled_cogs = None):
    """Generator for all enzymes with membership of all target_enzyme_cogs, without duplicate enzymes or redundant genes."""

    base_enzyme_genes = proposed_enzyme or []
    fulfilled_cogs = get_enzyme_cogs(base_enzyme_genes, target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict)

    ## Which COG will we try to find a member of?
    next_cog_to_fill = sorted(list(target_enzyme_cogs-fulfilled_cogs))[0]
    gene_members_of_cog = cog_gene_dict[next_cog_to_fill] 

    for gene in gene_members_of_cog:

        ## Check whether any already-present gene's COG set is a subset of the proposed gene's COG set, if so skip addition
        subset_found = False
        proposed_gene_cogs = set(gene_cog_dict[gene]) & target_enzyme_cogs
        for gene_cogs_set in get_gene_by_gene_cogs(base_enzyme_genes, target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict):
            if gene_cogs_set.issubset(proposed_gene_cogs):
                subset_found = True
                break
        if subset_found:
            continue

        ## Add gene to proposed enzyme
        proposed_enzyme = deepcopy(base_enzyme_genes)
        proposed_enzyme.append(gene)

        ## Determine which COG memberships are fulfilled by the genes in the proposed enzyme
        fulfilled_cogs = get_enzyme_cogs(proposed_enzyme, target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict)

        if (fulfilled_cogs & target_enzyme_cogs) == target_enzyme_cogs:
            ## Proposed enzyme has members of every required COG, so yield 
            enzyme = deepcopy(proposed_enzyme)
            proposed_enzyme.remove(gene)
            yield enzyme
        else:
            ## Proposed enzyme is still missing some COG members
            for enzyme in add_gene(target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict, cog_gene_dict, proposed_enzyme, fulfilled_cogs):
                yield enzyme
```

Input:

```
gene_cog_dict = {'gene1':['COG1','COG1003'], 'gene2':['COG2'], 'gene3':['COG273'], 'gene4':['COG1'], 'gene5':['COG273','COG71'], 'gene6':['COG1','COG273']}
cog_gene_dict = {'COG2': ['gene2'], 'COG1': ['gene1', 'gene4', 'gene6'], 'COG71': ['gene5'], 'COG273': ['gene3', 'gene5', 'gene6'], 'COG1003': ['gene1']}

target_enzyme_cogs = ['COG1','COG273']
```

Usage:

```
for enzyme in add_gene(target_enzyme_cogs, gene_cog_dict, cog_gene_dict):
    print enzyme
```

Output:

```
['gene1', 'gene3']
['gene1', 'gene5']
['gene4', 'gene3']
['gene4', 'gene5']
['gene6']
```

I have no idea about its performance though.

Answer (score 1):

One basic attack:

```
Keep your representation as it is for now.
Initialize a dictionary with the COGs as keys; each value is an initial count of 0.

Now start building your list of enzyme coverage sets (ecs_list), one ecs at a time.  Do this by starting at the front of the gene list and working your way to the end, considering all combinations.

Write a recursive routine to solve the remaining COGs in the enzyme.  Something like this:

def pick_a_gene(gene_list, cog_list, solution_set, cog_count_dict):
   pick the first gene in the list that is in at least one cog in the list.
   let the rest of the list be remaining_gene_list.
   add the gene to the solution set.
   for each of the gene's cogs:
      increment the cog's count in cog_count_dict
      remove the cog from cog_list (if it's still there).
   add the gene to the solution set.

   is there anything left in the cog_list?
   yes:
      pick_a_gene(remaining_gene_list, cog_list, solution_set, cog_count_dict)
   no:    # we have a solution: check it for minimality
      from every non-zero entry in cog_count_dict, subtract 1.  This gives us a list of excess coverage.
      while the excess list is not empty:
         pick the next gene in the solution set, starting from the *end* (if none, break the loop)
         if the gene's cogs are all covered by the excess:
            remove the gene from the solution set.
            decrement the excess count of each of its cogs.

      The remaining set of genes is an ECS; add it to ecs_list
```

Does this work for you?  I believe that it covers the minimal sets properly, given the well-behaved example you have.  Note that starting from the high end when we check minimality guards against a case like this:

```
gene1: cog1, cog5
gene2: cog2, cog5
gene3: cog3
gene4: cog1, cog2, cog4
enzyme: cog1 - cog5
```

We can see that we need gene3, gene4, and *either* gene1 or gene2.  If we eliminate from the low end, we'll toss out gene1 and never find that solution.  If we start from the high end, we'll eliminate gene2, but find that solution in a later pass of the main loop.

It's possible to construct a case in which there is a 3-way conflict of this ilk.  In that case, we'd have to write an extra loop in the minimality check to find them all.  However, I gather that your data aren't that nasty to us.

Answer (score 1):

```
def findGenes(seq1, seq2, llist):

    from collections import OrderedDict
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import product

    od  = OrderedDict()

    for b,a in llist:
        od.setdefault(a,[]).append(b)

    llv = []
    for k,v in od.items():
        if seq1 == k or seq2 == k:
            llv.append(v)

    # flat list needed for counting genes frequencies
    flatL = [ x for  sublist in llv for x in sublist]


    cFlatl = Counter(flatL)

    # this will gather genes that like gene6 have both sequencies
    l_lonely = []

    for k in cFlatl:
        if cFlatl[k] > 1:
            l_lonely.append(k)

    newL = []
    temp = []

    for sublist in llv:
        for el in sublist:
            if el not in l_lonely:
                  newL.append(el)
        temp.append(newL)
        newL = []

    # temp contains only genes that do not belong to both sequences
    # product will connect genes from different sequence groups
    p = product(*temp)

    for el in list(p):
        print(el)

    print(l_lonely)
```

**OUTPUT:**

lt = [('gene1', 'COG1'), ('gene1', 'COG1003'),('gene2', 'COG2'), ('gene3',  'COG273'),  ('gene4', 'COG1'),
      ('gene5', 'COG273'),('gene5', 'COG71'), ('gene6' ,'COG1'),('gene6', 'COG273')]

**findGenes('COG1', 'COG273', lt )**

('gene1', 'gene3')

('gene1', 'gene5')

('gene4', 'gene3')

('gene4', 'gene5')

['gene6']

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it for you?  Note that since you said you had a short set of COGs, I went ahead and did nested for loops; there may be ways to optimize this...

For future reference, please post any code that you've got along with your question.

```
import itertools

d = {'gene1':['COG1','COG1003'], 'gene2':['COG2'], 'gene3':['COG273'], 'gene4':['COG1'], 'gene5':['COG273','COG71'], 'gene6':['COG1','COG273']}

COGs = [set(['COG1','COG273'])] # example list of COGs containing only one enzyme; NOTE: your data should be a list of multiple sets

# create all pair-wise combinations of our data
gene_pairs = [l for l in itertools.combinations(d.keys(),2)]

found = set()
for pair in gene_pairs:

    join = set(d[pair[0]] + d[pair[1]]) # set of COGs for gene pairs

    for COG in COGs:

        # check if gene already part of enzyme
        if sorted(d[pair[0]]) == sorted(list(COG)):
            found.add(pair[0])
        elif sorted(d[pair[1]]) == sorted(list(COG)):
            found.add(pair[1])

        # check if gene combinations are part of enzyme
        if COG <= join and pair[0] not in found and pair[1] not in found:
            found.add(pair)

for l in found:
    if isinstance(l, tuple): # if tuple
        print l[0], l[1]
    else:
        print l
```